# How to use jest for testing abstract class in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

Hi I trying to test Abstract class using jest. But when ever try to do that. I'm getting the syntax error. I tried using type: module to import cosmos dependencies I got this error adding type:module in package.json

```
import { Constants, CosmosClient, ErrorResponse, FeedOptions, FeedResponse, ItemResponse, SqlQuerySpec, StatusCodes } from '@azure/cosmos';

/**
 * Abstract class with general CosmosDB utilities and wrappers.
 */
export abstract class AbstractCosmosService {

  // TODO: Cannot be abstract yet: microsoft/TypeScript#34516
  protected static CONNECTION_STRING: string;

  protected static get dbClient(): CosmosClient {
    return new CosmosClient(this.CONNECTION_STRING);
  }

  protected static recordRequestCharge(response: any): void {
    if (typeof response === 'object' && response && response.hasOwnProperty('requestCharge')) {
      // TODO: record request charge somehow
    }
  }
```

I'm getting the error
[image]

Comment: It looks like you don't have Typescript configured to work with Jest (or the other way around).

Comment: It is configured. Actually few test cases are even getting executed. I problem with only Abstract class

Comment: It's not really clear why that's an abstract class, but in general if you need to test an abstract class you can write a concrete test implementation and test that.